# How was the Dilophosaurus scene shot?

Tags: film-techniques, jurassic-park

In the movie Jurassic Park, What was the Dilophosaurus made of? Neither can I make it out be an animatronic robot like T-Rex/Triceratops nor a human costume like Velociraptor (since it was very small). Was it CGI, although it looked real?

Comment: Of course you can't make it out to be an animatronic or CGI, the movie didn't get its effects Oscar for nothing. ;-)

Comment: :) I thought it was coz of the ingenious "Shaving cream cryo can embryo storage" that they won it!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its achieved by [Animatronic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animatronics) robot. [Click here](https://www.stanwinstonschool.com/blog/making-jurassic-park-dilophosaurus-aka-spitter) for full details with picture, to know how it is achieved. Few more picture of Dilophosaurus's making are present [here](https://www.stanwinstonschool.com/blog/jurassic-park-dilophosaurus-dinosaur-puppet).

Comment: and here I was looking for the clues in "legacy studios" website... Thanks